# How to avoid the error "Unknown prop <> on tag. Remove this prop from the element"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please, how can I rewrite this code another way to avoid the error below?

```
     render() {
            const { children, ...props } = this.props;
            return <div {...props} ref={this.setRef}>{children}</div>
      }
```

I get this error:

Unknown prop `onClickOutside` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over)

Comment: do you see `onClickOutside` on this list? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove in from the `...props` you transfer:

```
render() {
            const { children, onClickOutside, ...props } = this.props;
            return <div {...props} ref={this.setRef}>{children}</div>
      }
```

If you want `onClickOutside` to map to the `onClick` of the `div`, then handle this explicitly:

```
render() {
            const { children, onClickOutside, ...props } = this.props;
            return <div {...props} onClick={onClickOutside} ref={this.setRef}>{children}</div>
      }
```

Any version of React < 16.x, have a whitelist of available attributes.  So, all attributes passed to elements must be in the whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

Native DOM elements only allowed to have Native DOM attributes. You can't pass any attribute (prop) you want.
If you know what valid props you need to this element you can destruct them out of props and pass them explicit.
For example:

```
 render() {
            const { children, onClickOutside } = this.props;
            return <div onClick={onClickOutside} ref={this.setRef}>{children}</div>
      }
```